# Is it possible to have sequential ring call-forwarding and internet voice-mail in plain old-telephone system instead of VOIP?

Tags: voip

Is it possible to have sequential ring call-forwarding on a plain old-telephone system (non Voice over Internet Protocol VOIP)?

Though non-VOIPs might not exist in America, can I have all my features such as internet accessible voice-mail, call-forwarding onto multiple numbers, on a Plain Old Telephone System that uses analog but automated switching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any analog switch gear (5ESS, DMS100, etc.) that directly supports such selective call forwarding. However, it's possible to set up a chain of CFNA (call-forward-no-answer) numbers -- A goes to B after so many rings, then similar CFNA applies to B, C, etc. Of course, this is an independent setting *per line*, and there's usually only so long the source line is going to support ringing.

(Some digital PBX's do support this sort of sequential hunt-group. And they can hav POTS cards in them.)

Answer (score 2):

Not all private telephone systems, or PBX's, are IP based. Both call forwarding and hunt groups (sequential call forwarding) are basic features for most any PBX - the hunt group options are usually *sequential*, broadcast (all phone lines in the group), and top down.

Hunting or forwarding to PSTN (plain old telephone service) phones (vs PBX phone lines) can be an advanced feature that not all PBX's will support because simultaneously ringing a PSTN phone introduces additional complexity. Think about it - the PBX's Call Forward All simply hairpins the call back out to a second PSTN trunk line but then control of the call is lost. Thus, the advanced nature of simultaneously ringing a PSTN phone and PBX phone line - the PBX has to monitor the call setup messaging on that second PSTN trunk to be able to terminate that forwarded call if noone answers for example. Otherwise, incoming calls would get the PSTN (or cell) phones personal voicemail versus the companies voicemail. Also, how would the PBX know to stop the hunt? It's an advanced feature to simultaneously ring PBX lines and PSTN (or cell phone) lines.

In terms of Internet accessible voicemail, many PBX's will have a voicemail feature but it is actually a separate system. For example, it is possible to have an advanced IP-based voicemail system with email integration (voicemail as a .mp3 or .wav attachment) integrated with a very basic analog key system.